# With how many ways can we place 20 cars in 30 spots.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

So we have 4 white cars, 6 black cars, 6 blue cars and 4 silver cars. We want to place them in a 30 spot parking. We choose to place the cars with the following order white cars first, then silver after them blue and finally the black cars. How many ways are there to place them?

My thought is: at first we have 30 positions and we choose 4 for the white ones, then we have 26 positions and we choose 4 for the silver cars, then 22 free positions to choose 6 for the blue cars and then 16 positions to choose 6 for the black ones.

So we have $\binom{30}{4}\binom{26}{4}\binom{22}{6}\binom{16}{6} \approx 2.44 \times 10^{17}$.

Is my approach correct or am I way off?

Comment: The reasoning is fine. You really shouldn’t use $=$, though, when you mean $\approx$, and the product is actually $2.448\times10^{17}$ to four significant figures.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It is worthwhile to point out of course that the order in which you choose the cars is irrelevant. Therefore, your current answer (which is correct) is also equal to $\binom{30}{6}\binom{24}{4}\binom{20}{6}\binom{14}{4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would answer as follows: Imagine the cars with the order we want adjacent each other to $20$ slots. There are now $10$ free slots that we may throw in between the cars. This can be done in
$$
\underbrace{21 \cdot 21 \cdots 21}_{10} = 21^{10} 
$$
Taking in consideration permutations for cars of the same color, the total number should be
$$
21^{10} \cdot 4! \cdot 4! \cdot 6! \cdot 6! 
$$

Comment: Interesting approach, so this solution applies to the restriction that cars with the same color must remain as a "group" and we can have spaces either at the beginning or the end of the parking, and between cars of different color, right? So my solution is if we simply place the cars without restrictions?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly as I see it.